# Deciding between an IsDeleted/DateDeleted column or a separate History table?

Tags: sql-server, database-design

We have a table that stores nothing but an `AccountId`, `TagId`, and `DateCreated`. Users can update the Tags on accounts, which adds or remove records from this table. No tag can exist more than once on an account, but the same tag can be added and removed multiple times. This table is primarily used in queries users build to filter accounts using either `JOIN` or `EXISTS` on the tag table.

I've been asked to start recording tag history, and I'm trying to decide if it would be better to use an `IsDeleted` and/or `DateDeleted` column on the existing table, or if I should create a separate history table that stores this data instead.

The primary purpose of tracking the history would be to run reports on a specific point in time. For example, getting data on accounts that had TagA on them during January 2013.

What factors should I consider when trying to decide between the two?

Comment: Well, can tags be deleted, then when they get re-created do they keep the same TagId? If so then a history table makes more sense. If they are considered a completely new entity when they get re-created, then a history table will be of marginal use, since for any tag, there could only ever be one row marking the delete.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Its possible they get the same tag re-added, so the TagId would be the same. Right now we have about 5 different tags (more expected to be added) which can be added or removed from accounts as needed. No account can have the same tag more than once, but an account can have the same tag added and removed multiple times.

Comment: If you don't have the history table and the is_deleted indicator, how do you respond to the point in time query requirement? Table point in time can lead to very poorly performing sql, but it does drive the design.

Comment: Currently, we don't. But such a request has come up for some new reports we're building, which is the purpose of adding the tag history to our tables.

Answer (score 9):

The problem with `IsDeleted` is its low cadinality: 0 or 1. Which makes it unindexable and since all your queries will add `IsDeleted = 0` to the WHERE (or JOIN) conditions this apparent trivial change complicates a *lot* of things. You covering indexes will all of the sudden require lookups into the base table to decide if the row qualifies or not. There are measures that can improve behavior, but they have to be properly considered and *consistently* deployed (note that some of these mitigation are mutually exclusive, evaluate them separately):

- add `IsDeleted` as the leftmost key in the clustered index. This effectively 'splits' the clustered table into two regions ('deleted' and 'active'). It also forces de-facto the `IsDeleted` column in every non-clustered index, thus avoiding the need to lookup the value.
- add `IsDeleted` as a leftmost key in *every* non-clustered index. May sound extreme, but can be quite effective, provided that **all** queries specify `IsDeleted` in the WHERE.
- add `IsDeleted` as an included column to every non-clustered index. Unlike the options above this does not change seek/range/lookup semantics of the exiting indexes, but makes the `IsDeleted` check filtering available in *every* access path. Can be quite effective specially if `IsDeleted = 1` occurs seldom.
- make the non-clustered indexes filtered by `IsDeleted = 0`. May be effective on large tables, but is a bit dangerous as the filtered indexes become unusable for queries interested in the *deleted* rows.

A separate table for history makes a much more cleaner cut from the engine point of view: is a *different* table, no messy/risky plan choices to cope with. But it is much more impact on the application. If looking up the history of a row is the exception, the application changes are reasonable easy then I would consider this option first, as it has the least risk of (severe) performance regression.

I would strongly advise against mixed solutions (eg. tags and tags_history table *and* a view that unions them), such solutions have all the disadvantages mentioned above without any advantage. In general, anything that claims 'minimal impact' or 'transparent change' is snake oil. This (adding application layer row versioning/row history) is, by definition, a high impact change which will ripple big time in the application.